# What does `\a` do?

Tags: macros, accents

I wanted to make

`\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}`

but apparently `\a` is already defined. However, I couldn't figure out what it does through experimentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\a` is a LaTeX core instruction for generating a letter with a diacritical mark.

`\a{accent}{letter}`

The command is intended for the case when the normal accent commands of the form `\accent{letter}` or `\Accent{letter}` are not available locally for some reason.

Accents can be, for example:

```
"'`^=.~Hruv
```

##### Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\a"a \a'b \^c \a=d \a.e \a~f \a{H}g \a{r}h \a{u}i \a{v}j

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

`\a'` produces the same accent as `\'` but is usable in `tabbing` and other places where `\'` has other meanings. It is usable with all the accent commands.

Its actual definition is

```
\def\@tabacckludge#1{\expandafter\@changed@cmd
                                 \csname\string#1\endcsname\relax}
\let\a=\@tabacckludge
```

Comment: Thank you very much!